# Use `next` with an accumulator argument in a `reduce`

Tags: ruby, coding-style, rubocop

There is a cop: [`RuboCop::Cop::Lint::NextWithoutAccumulator`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.36.0/RuboCop/Cop/Lint/NextWithoutAccumulator).

Is anyone able to explain what this cop is for, how is it supposed to improve the code in in what way?

Does it improve readability, efficiency?

[github code](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/lint/next_without_accumulator.rb).

Comment: Have you tried to run the two examples from the cop's documentation that you linked to?

Comment: @muistooshort shame on me - I did not :( I hope late evening acquits this hasty question at least a bit..

Answer (score 8):

Lets consider sample code from the documentation:

```
# bad
result = (1..4).reduce(0) do |acc, i|
  next if i.odd?
  acc + i
end
```

If you try this in the console, you will get `NoMethodError` exception for the `nil` object. This is because `next` "returns" `nil` if there is no object specified. You can treat it as `return` for iterators.

For [`reduce` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) it may result in some unexpected behavior as it needs some value returned by the block. If `i` is odd, then `next` is evaluated and block gives `nil` as the result. In the following iterator `acc` is equal to `nil` and it can't add integer to it. In our example, first iteration is for `i = 1`, `next` sets `acc` to `nil` as the result of the block.

In some cases you can get correct value for the enumerable, but in general it is safer to specify value for `next` inside.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but the question may be out-of-bounds (as off-topic, requiring an opinion).

Comment: Check @gregory-ray response for the workaround code sample

Answer (score 2):

## Bad

```
result = (1..4).reduce(0) do |acc, i|
  next if i.odd?
  acc + i
end
```

## Good

```
result = (1..4).reduce(0) do |acc, i|
  next acc if i.odd?
  acc + i
end
```

As @smefju pointed out, next by itself implicitly returns `nil` and will cause a `NoMethodError` when it is passed in as the parameter of the next execution of the block.